# Text Background in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, text, background, transparent

Hello I am wondering how I would make the background of my text look like my slider at [my website](http://deadlydragongaming.com) I am using a wordpress theme so just having a background for the text would be perfect Otherwise it looks like [this](http://deadlydragongaming.com/watch-dogs)

```
<h1 class = "myClass">My Text Here</h1>
```

I want to give it a transparent black background in css

```
.myClass{
      font-size:70px;
      color: white;
}
```

I also need it to only be behind my text I dont want the background going the full width of the page

the solution was rather easy

```
padding: 4px 0;
font-size: 70px;
color: white;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
line-height: 95px;
display: inline;
```

Comment: can you add some HTML and CSS to your question please?  That way the question won't suffer from link rot if/when the content on those pages changes.

Comment: Please DO NOT link to external resources (your site) that will change and be of no value to anyone looking at this question.

Comment: code/no/code... it's totally unclear what you're asking for in either cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, add a line-height

```
.WatchDogs {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 95px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Ok now I just need to make it not as wide :D

Answer (score 1):

All you need is CSS **background-color** coinciding with a rgba() color value. The following code will give you a 50% opacity black background. See more on [rgba](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/)

```
.myClass {
    font-size:70px;
    color: white;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
```

Comment: ok but I only want it to be around the text not spanning the entire container

Comment: that is the color I want however now it is a long wide skinny bar

Comment: @arcreigh are you referring to a stroke around your text? The code I provided is exactly the code used on your website. You can add a **padding: 4px 0;** to make it wider (as your site does)

Comment: no go to the here link it will show you what it is doing

Comment: padding did not solve the long skinny problem. sorry about my lack of description not easy to describe :D

Comment: @arcreigh you're going to need to post your HTML code if you want more help

Comment: its a wordpress theme im not using any html myself as I am using visual composer

Answer (score 1):

Also add display:inline to have it stretch to the width of the text.